# is it possible to list all group in redis 6.0+

Tags: redis

Now I am encount a problem in my app shows like this:

```
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: NOGROUP No such key 'pydolphin:stream:article' or consumer group 'pydolphin:stream:group:article' in XREADGROUP with GROUP option
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:135) ~[jedis-3.6.0.jar!/:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:169) ~[jedis-3.6.0.jar!/:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:223) ~[jedis-3.6.0.jar!/:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:352) ~[jedis-3.6.0.jar!/:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBinaryMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:304) ~[jedis-3.6.0.jar!/:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.xreadGroup(BinaryJedis.java:4781) ~[jedis-3.6.0.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisStreamCommands.lambda$xReadGroup$17(JedisStreamCommands.java:364) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.lambda$doInvoke$2(JedisConnection.java:176) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.doWithJedis(JedisConnection.java:799) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
    ... 17 more
```

now I want to see how many group in redis, to my surprise, I could not found any command to do this after read the xgroup document. is it possible to list all groups in redis 6.0+ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [XINFO GROUPS](https://redis.io/commands/xinfo-groups) command returns an array of all groups registered for a given stream. It has been available since the introduction of streams in 5.0.

For each group it also gives the current number of group consumers, how many entries have been read but not yet acknowledged, and the latest ID seen by any of the group's consumers.